# Vuetify [v-select] trigger when menu is opened

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need help trying to detect the moment when the menu in a select is being opened and shown to the users.

Is there any method or watch that i can use to trigger the moment when the menu is being displayed?

Here a simple codepen with a v-select.

codepen.io/xmorelll/pen/bGMppWO?editors=101

Thank you!

Comment: I could'nt find any usable event. U can combine focus/click event with a check for `v-select v-select--is-menu-active` class

Comment: With this solution I think I will have almost all the situations controle, however the user can set the focus with tabs and open the menu with space.  I think... I could also watch the keydown event

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution extending the VSelect component from vuetify:

```
import { VSelect } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
    extends: VSelect,
    watch: {
        isMenuActive(val) {
            this.$emit('openMenu', val);
        }
    }
}
```

With this component the VSelect will do an emit when the menu changes his status

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable *(which is named `toggleSelect` in this example)* that will control the visibility of the `<v-select/>` and its `<v-menu/>` (the dropdown options). `<v-select/>` has [`menu-props`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#api) which we can use to control the menu's visibility. For the select field, we can simply use `v-if` to hide it.

```html
<v-btn 
  ...
  @click="toggleSelect = !toggleSelect"
>
  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-select
  :items="headers"
  v-if="toggleSelect"
  :menu-props="{value: toggleSelect}"
/>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  headers: [...],
  toggleSelect: false,  // let's not show the <v-select/> at first load.
})
```

Here is an example [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-resonance-nosgh?file=/src/components/Playground.vue) with `<v-data-table/>` implementation.

Comment: mmm... But i would like to have the v-select always visible. I am working in a form.

Comment: then you need to initialize `toggleSelect` as true so to be always opened. Please try it and let me know